# High performance code on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, profiling, latency

I would like to know the best way to profile app code on OS X.  I have a nano-second resolution timer and it seems after some baseline testing that I am hitting a kernel syscall context switch of about 45 micro (macbook 2ghz core2 duo model).

I've noticed that if I let my app cycle every now and then I can get a scheduling context switch of about 25,000-50,000 micro.  I am testing some algorithms, and I want to limit the effects of this.

What I really want is to be able to set the processor affinity of a task and also to set the main thread priority to realtime, which is not a bad thing because one day this Macbook may be used as a low-latency controller for something.  Any ideas on how to do this on snow leopard / XCode?

Comment: If you want a guaranteed low-latency controller device, a personal computer isn't going to cut it. Something like a [microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) (e.g. a [programmable logic controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_controller)) is what's usually used for this kind of situation, if you rather avoid the costly context switches.

Comment: you would start by separating your realtime/high-priority program from your app's main thread. all that happens on the main thread is *certainly not* high priority. (since you said "app", i assume you are referring to a program with a ui, rather than something like a utility or agent)

Comment: If you're trying to profile very fast portions of code, consider placing them in a loop and repeat the operation 1000+ times and measure that. At least that's how I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Shark in Xcode.  There's also DTrace.